# Apply RGB colors to HSV one-color image

Tags: python, opencv, rgb, hsv, bgr

I have a **HSV** image( PNG ) with [one color and white(transparent) background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zM5Y.jpg).
I want to change the image's color with the following **RGB** values:

```
rgb(197, 140, 133);
rgb(236, 188, 180); 
rgb(209, 163, 164); 
rgb(161, 102, 94); 
rgb(80, 51, 53);
rgb(89, 47, 42);
```

After the color is changed I need to make the white background transparent. I suppose this is done via *alpha channel=0*, but it's unclear to me how.
How do I do this? I'd like to understand the way *RGB->HSV->BGR* conversions works, I'll need it in the future.

So far, I've been testing in Python & CV2 and I managed to change the Hue to a random value, but it's not the solution I need.

P.S. I do **NOT** own this picture, it's used just for the demo.